# How to use main words alone and find a specific line in python3?

Tags: python

How to use main words alone and find a specific line in python3?

```
input_file = "firstline","B. DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY TO BE INSURED"

for line in input_file:
    if "B. DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY TO BE INSURED" in line:
         print(line)
```

> Instead of giving ("B. DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY TO BE INSURED")full
>   line, i want to give the main words alone such as DESCRIPTION, 
>   PROPERTY, INSURED
>
> Expected Output:

```
 B. DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY TO BE INSURED
```

Comment: Simple solution, you can filter out Stop words for example "a","we","to","for". 

Even better, you can use parts of speech tags and extract "Noun", "Verbs" etc as desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
input_file = "firstline","B. DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY TO BE INSURED"
words = ['DESCRIPTION', 'PROPERTY', 'INSURED']
for line in input_file:
    if all([word in line for word in words]):
        print(line)
```